# Edit profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

What I need is an edit profile form to edit `username`, `password` and `avatar`. But these fields are in two `models.User` and `allusers` (OneToOne). How can I create an edit profile form by combining the fields of both?

Models.py

```
class allusers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='retest/static/images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Comment: what exactly is stopping your form from updating two models at once?

Comment: use forms,ModelForm in forms.py. or else try something and post the code if you face any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom form and handle it in the view.

Here's a simple example.

**forms.py**

```
class UserEditForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    avatar = forms.FileField()
```

**views.py**

```
def user_edit_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES['file']:
        form = UserEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            your_file = request.FILES['file']
            new_username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            new_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            all_user = allusers.objects.get(user=user)
            user.username = new_username
            user.set_password(new_password)
            user.save()
            alluser.avatar = your_file
            alluser.save()
            return render(.................)
        return HttpResponse(......)
```